# Unity3d c# help, spawn itempickups

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my name is Victor and i am creating a doodle jump game in unity c# and i need help. I got to the step where i need to make itempick ups. Itempickups are boosts like helicopter, shield and others. I want to create an item pickup , the helicopter. The problem i am facing is that i created an object that will be my helicopter hat which when you will touch it will destroy and it will spawn in a place above the player.
The code is:

```
public GameObject helicopter;
public Transform trans;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Virtaliot") 
    {
        helicopter.SetActive(false);
        GameObject helicopters;
        helicopters = Instantiate(helicopter, trans.position, trans.rotation) as GameObject;
    }
}
```

here are some screenshots
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gitwl2dly0thj6n/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: What is that script attached to? The player or the pickup? Further you probably miss setting the parent. Also, since you didn't specify what exactly doesn't work, I assume it's not instantiating ( or at least it seems like it's not), did you check in the inspector if the object shows up?

Comment: Hey, can you please help me through teamviewer, i can't explain so well, please can you check through team viewer?

Comment: Sorry, can't do that, I don't have the time. Just provide some more information about on which object is that script, where should that object end up (in hierarchy), what is the `trans` variable referring to and what is the tag `Virtaliot` reffering to. That should be the information someone needs to help you.

Comment: So the trans in the position where the helicopter needs to be positioned after oncolissionentering, virtaliot is helicopter in russian, the script is attached to trans, wich is the place where it neds to be spawned after  touching it, and it shouldn't be in hirearchy, it needs to spawn i made that and after it touches the player it needs to be positioned on the player's top!

Comment: Does `trans` actually have a collider and a rigidbody? Thats required for collision/triggering detection. I suggest to actually put the script on the main player object since that will probably have a collider and a rigidbody. What I meant with the hierarchy part is that you should make that spawned object a child of the player (or more precisely the trans) so it will be always at the correct position (moving with the player). The hierarchy is a representation of all objects in the scene, so if an object doesn't show up in the hierarchy, it's not in the scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really the best way of doing this. I suggest that you don't need to instantiate the hat at all. A nicer way of doing this would be to add your hat object as a child of the player in the inspector and call `SetActive(false)` on it at `Start`. Then, after getting a reference to the hat in your player script, you could simply use

```
public GameObject helicopterChild; //reference to hat

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Virtaliot") 
    {
        helicopterChild.SetActive(True); //Show the hat on the players head
        Destroy(col.gameObject); //Destroy the pickup shown in the world
        // you will also need to make the player fly up
    }
}
```

to turn the hat on, destroy the pick up and the apply the flying effect. This assumes that you are stopping the flying effect elsewhere.

Comment: wait, you said in the script that i a mthe player and then i need to destroy  the player? is this script attached to the player?

Comment: Yes, this is attached to the player. The `Destroy(col.gameObject)` part will destroy what you collide with (the hat pickup) , not the player.

Comment: oh, i understand, thansk ,  iwll try and i will let you know!

Comment: Wonderful! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Write the `Instantiate()` function above the `SetActive()` function. I think the script stops after you disable it, so it will never reach the instantiation. Maybe you could write a debug log so you can see if it is executed.

Comment: hey, it doesn't work, may e you could help me through team viewer, casn you do that? i would apreciate this!

Comment: i think the problem is not in the code but it is in the hirearchy, i amde something wrong there, i thing i didn't atrtach the children corectly or something like that!

Comment: so.. can you help me?